# mouse click event in openCVsharp

Tags: c#, opencv, mouseevent

I'm trying to get mouse position inside and opened window in c# using openCVsharp methods.

First I define a callback function:

```
public void mc(MouseEvent me, int x, int y, MouseEvent me2) {}
```

Then in initiating phase I open the window an assign that callback function to it:

```
CvMouseCallback mo = new CvMouseCallback(mc);
Cv.NamedWindow("capture");
Cv.SetMouseCallback("capture", mo);
```

But callback is not called with mouse clicks in the opened window.

I tried to google it but no sample code or instructions was found for opencvsharp. And since in openCV its just a regular callback method -no need to that CVmousecallback - I couldn't find out how to perform this on openCVsharp.

Has anybody done that in openCVsharp?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Mat img = ...;
Window foo = new Window("bar", img); // class OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.Window
foo.OnMouseCallback += new CvMouseCallback(mc);
```

I also tried SetMouseCallback method on the first time, but it didn't work for me either.